# Bitwise XOR on address in GoLang

Tags: pointers, go, bit-manipulation, xor

I was trying to implement the XOR Linked List in Go where I had to store the XORed address. In C/C++ it's quite simple

```
(*struct_type)(([unsigned] int)nodeA ^ ([unsigned] int)nodeB)
```

I tried a similar approach in Go. I had a struct named Node with two nodes nodeA and nodeB. To get this I tried the following ways:

```
*Node(uint(nodeA) ^ uint(nodeB))
```

Which gave me an error saying, can't convert type Node to uint.
Another way I tried, which I was sure woundn't work, was

```
nodeA ^ nodeB
```

Is there a way to parse the address to int type, XOR them and then re-parse them into Node address? Or does Go provide a simple solution to this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is not supported by Go. You can force it, by using the `reflect` and `unsafe` packages, but generally this is frowned upon.

Comment: might this helps https://github.com/anacrolix/dht/blob/master/int160.go

Comment: Thank you @Flimzy for pointing that out. I'm still learning it.

Comment: Thank you @mh-cbon for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [unsafe.Pointer](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) for pointer arithmetic:

```
a := &T{}
b := &T{}
x := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a)) ^ uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(b))
y := (*T)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a)) ^ x))
fmt.Println(b == y)  // prints true
```

The GC uses pointers to track memory. If the code is rewritten to

```
a := &T{}
b := &T{}
x := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a)) ^ uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(b))
b = nil // clear all pointers to struct
b = (*T)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(a)) ^ x))
```

then it's possible for the GC to collect the struct pointed to by `b` before the last assignment to `b`.

It's not possible to implement a safe XOR list in Go because the GC can collect the elements.

Don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't implement an XOR Linked List in Go. The Go garbage collector (GC) uses pointer values to keep track of in-use memory. If you mangle a pointer value, the GC will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing out that Go doesn't support pointer arithmetic. I did a quick research and, found and used the *usafe* package Go provides just in case "unsafe" work in needed. I solved the problem with the following lines of code:

```
a := unsafe.Pointer(nodeA)
b := unsafe.Pointer(nodeB)
return (*Node)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(a) ^ uintptr(b)))
```

The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) to unsafe package.